# How to fix the time formatting issue

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, client-server

Trying to populate the sheet data in HTML web app, my data consists Time(24 hrs format) but in web apps, it's reflecting in a different format.

Attached Image for reference

[image]

```js
function doGet() {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  t.data = SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1ZPbCZWvEIJ7rpYxyfD4yiWrnC11RT9I_96kCndAJmdI')
      .getActiveSheet()
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
  return t.evaluate();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a following modification? [`getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues()) was used for this situation.

#### From :

```
function doGet() {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  t.data = SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1ZPbCZWvEIJ7rpYxyfD4yiWrnC11RT9I_96kCndAJmdI')
      .getActiveSheet()
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
  return t.evaluate();
}
```

#### To :

```
function doGet() {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  t.data = SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1ZPbCZWvEIJ7rpYxyfD4yiWrnC11RT9I_96kCndAJmdI')
      .getActiveSheet()
      .getDataRange()
      .getDisplayValues(); // Modified
  return t.evaluate();
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between getValues and getDisplayValues?  In the documentation  it just says "Returns the rectangular grid of values for this range" for both of them.

Comment: @Cooper This method is returned the display value as strings. In this situation, I thought that this method may be effectively. ``setNumberFormat('@')`` also might be able to be used to obtain almost the same result. You can see the detail information of ``getDisplayValues()`` from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues()

Comment: Thanks for that input. I appreciate it.  It's amazing how much information is in the documentation and how easy it is to overlook it.

Comment: @Cooper Because by using this, it can avoid the internal auto conversion, I think that this method is convenient.

Comment: @Tanaike.. Thanks

Comment: @Kiiran Shetty Welcome. Thank you, too.