# How do I get an exact copy of a cell as it is shown?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets Script, how can I take an exact copy from a cell as it is shown in the spreadsheet?

For example, currently if I create a variable to fetch a value of a cell that on the spreadsheet appears as '-£20', it will fetch the value '-20'. I would like this to be fetched as '-£20', the same as it's written in the spreadsheet.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix the time formatting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45449705/how-to-fix-the-time-formatting-issue)

Answer (score 2):

**Example Script showing the difference between getValue() and getDisplayValue() for a cell containing 29 British Pound Sterling**

```
function getMyCellValue() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getActiveCell();
  MyLogger('getValue() = ' + rg.getValue());
  MyLogger('getDispValue = ' + rg.getDisplayValue());
}
[02|26|18:59:27] - getValue() = 29
[02|26|18:59:28] - getDispValue = £29.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `range.getDisplayValue()`. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue(). There is also `range.getDisplayValues()`.